# How to remove last selected file in Xcode 5 project navigator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

My `Xcode 5` is crashing continuously for one project when i am changing project navigator selection from xib file to any other file. so how to reset `Xcode 5` preferences in mavericks?

[image]

```
Process:         Xcode [11348]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0 (3332.22)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3332022000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [476]
Responsible:     Xcode [11348]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-19 20:17:51.222 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  7CAA04DB-9AE5-4DB6-4EA0-12DF215191FF

Sleep/Wake UUID: BC5C337A-14F4-4375-8EF4-397D0F2DB159

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1412
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-4510/CocoaIntegration/ResourceManagement/IBCocoaResourceManager.m:73
Details:  result should be an instance inheriting from NSImage, but it is IBCIImage
Object:   <IBCocoaResourceManager: 0x7f85f54072a0>
Method:   -placeholderResourceContentForMediaType:originalValue:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f85f0c150e0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me a few weeks ago. I don't think I had to reset anything. Have you tried deleting your derived data, and rebooting your machine?

Comment: @jhilgert00 deleting UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `.xcodeproj` in Finder, and right click, select `show package contents`. Then select the `project.xcworkspace` file within and `show package contents` on that as well, then open the `xcuserdata` folder, open the `yourusername.xcuserdatad` folder. You will see a `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file. Delete it. Then open back up your `.xcodeproj` file.

Comment: Apple Bug ID 15502725.